# Difficulty finding point of inflection

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

The Problem is...

$N(t)=\frac{200,000}{1+999e^{-0.4t}}$

Use logarithmic differentiation to find the time to the point of inflection.

I know that in order to find the point of inflection I must set the second derivative equal to $0$.

And I believe I have solved for the first derivative, but I need help with the second. 
for the first derivative, I have...
$N'(t)= \frac{(999)(-0.4)(200,000)e^{-0.4t}}{(1+999e^{-0.4t})^2}$

PLEASE HELP, even if you just know how to start it up, that would be a huge help!

Comment: You dropped a negative on your first derivative; it should be $N'(t)=\frac{79,920,000e^{-0.4t}}{(1+999e^{-0.4t})^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wolfram Alpha (the savior for nasty problems such as these), the second derivative is $$N''(t) = \frac{e^{-0.4t}(31,936,032,000e^{0.8t}-31,968,000e^{1.2t})}{(999+e^{0.4t})^3}.$$

Setting the second derivative equal to zero results in $t = \frac{5\ln(999)}{2}\approx17.2669$, so the inflection point is at that point.